# Can I use Mix_OpenAudio and SDL_OpenAudio in the same game?

Tags: c++, audio, sdl

I am trying to finish up a school project using SDL 1.2, but I have hit a snag that I can't get by.

The game has several game state modules, each with a function
**int Run(SDL_Surface *screen);**

In each module, Run() initializes audio, runs through its loop, then closes audio before returning.

all of the modules use Mix_OpenAudio() and Mix_CloseAudio() to init/deinit the sound, and work fine together.

The only exception is the cinematic movie module where I have used SDL_FFMpeg to show a movie. This module forces me to use **SDL_OpenAudio()** instead.

SDL_OpenAudio fails the first time with the error "Audio device is already open", but then works the second time.

Once I have run the movie module, all the sound in the other modules stops working even though all their functions return 0 for success.

anyone have any idea whats going on?

Comment: Show some code from the relevant modules?

Comment: ugh...thanks anyways..but what finally fixed the problem enrages me thouroughly. I finally got fed up and just stuck 5 more SDL_CloseAudio() calls at the end of each module...and wouldn't ya know it, the problem went away! so I removed the extra calls one by one until......I had the same number as when I started, except that it still worked...

Comment: The above comment sounds like your compiler didn't notice that there were changes. That can happen. One thing you should do, if you are puzzled about why things are not working, is to force the compiler to recompile the whole project. Delete all the .obj-files by hand or use some "clear project" command in your IDE. Run again and see, if it works now. If it's still not work ask SO. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[The conflicts chapter](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/docs/SDL_mixer/SDL_mixer.html#SEC5) tells this :

> When using SDL_mixer functions you
>   need to avoid the following functions
>   from SDL:
>
> SDL_OpenAudio
>       Use Mix_OpenAudio instead.

therefore I guess the answer to your question is : you can not mix `SDL_OpenAudio()` and `MIX_OpenAudio()` functions.

Comment: Jan 4: "I am trying to finish up a school project using SDL 1.2"
    
you're a little late =)

Comment: @Nick Better late, then never ;)

Answer (score 0):

`SDL_OpenAudio()` and `SDL_CloseAudio()` is a pair function, once you open audio some where, you must close it, or you'll get the error like

> *Audio device is already open*

While using `SDL_OpenAudio()`, it's a singleton, by trace into SDL source code, you may find that there was a `current_audio` object and this is the global audio object. If you open multiple audio files in the same time, this may cause race condition.

I think this pair function only fit for audio/video playing, not for game(in game there may be multiple audio source at the same time), because you'll probably not playing multiple audio/video time at the same time in a single process. So before you start to play a video/audio file, you must ensure that the SDL's audio status is `SDL_AUDIO_STOPPED` by calling `SDL_GetAudioStatus()`. After playing a audio/video file, you should do something like that:

> ```
> SDL_LockAudio();
> SDL_CloseAudio();
> SDL_UnlockAudio();
> ```

This will ensure that the audio stop completely. BTW, the lock/unlock operation is to ensure that your audio callback code do not running at the point.